# XKCD browser dependency issues

Tags: package-management

I have followed exactly the same instructions for installing xkcd-browser but facing the dependency issues

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brianrobles204/xkcd-browser; 
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install xkcd-browser
```

Source : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/20-must-have-ubuntu-showdown-apps

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
xkcd-browser : Depends: gir1.2-gwibber-gtk-0.2 but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue because its short of dependency-hell?

Comment: Are you running either 11.10 or 12.04?

Comment: @tgm4883 i was using 12.04 but now upgraded to 12.10 & i think now this its ppa doesn't work anymore. Still for people using 12.04 this needs to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Find these packages and replace existing files with these.

```
gir1.2-gwibber-0.2_3.4.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
gir1.2-gwibber-gtk-0.2_3.4.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
libgwibber-gtk2_3.4.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

One place where you could find them is

http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/

You can use dpkg -i to install these.

Comment: But @razor aren't these packages specific for amd64 architecture? mine is i386 so i don't think this will work.